# Get form requests from a HTTP request in Java

Tags: java, web, client-server

I have created a HTTP server which works perfectly! No problems there,
using Sockets and ServerSockets.

Now I need to make the Form entries - which are done in the web browser and when they are submitted, they are processed by Java.

I've tried making a form, then pressing sumbit, except it's given a 501 error... The first part is 'POST /'. I suppose that means a hidden variable passed... But how do I make the server recognise the hidden variable, and make it process it?

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: That just means that a HTTP POST request is been sent to the URL `/`. The parameters are just in the request body, the part after the request headers. Just learn basic HTTP: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/ Unless for hobby/learning purposes, I'd rather not reinvent a HTTP server if you're already asking questions like this.

Comment: I make the HTTP server for a friend. He doesn't like Apache or IIS, so he asked me. I took it a little further and started making all sorts of other things for it. (Yes this is just a learning purpose)

Thanks, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you decode the parameters depends on a number of things. If the request is a POST request then the values are part of the request body (this is, the values are sent after a blank link that separates the head and the body of the request). The encoding of the request body is then either "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" or "multipart/form-data". You can read how these two encodings work here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4

I assume that this is a toy project and that you want to write this code yourself. Otherwise there are many server implementations of the HTTP protocol for Java out there...